# Why does font-size not appear to affect my buttons that I have created?

Tags: html, css

I am making a game of chess, and have five buttons for if you resign, if you draw, and to reset the game. However, I want them to appear bigger, and the css I have is not doing that. I have tried using
`font-size: 3rem;`, but that does not appear to work.

Here is my HTML:

```css
div.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Resign for White</button>
    <button>Resign for Black</button>
    <button>Offer Draw</button>
    <button>Accept Draw</button>
    <button>RESET GAME</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the browser apply a default font-size to button

Answer (score 3):

Because button has its own `font-size` (`13px` in my Chrome instead of `inherit`) and you are targeting only parent div.

```css
div.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
div.buttons button {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Resign for White</button>
    <button>Resign for Black</button>
    <button>Offer Draw</button>
    <button>Accept Draw</button>
    <button>RESET GAME</button>
</div>
```

or you can set font-size directly to button:

```css
div.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
div.buttons button {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Resign for White</button>
    <button>Resign for Black</button>
    <button>Offer Draw</button>
    <button>Accept Draw</button>
    <button>RESET GAME</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is wrong, you have to fix it like follow:

```css
div button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>Resign for White</button>
    <button>Resign for Black</button>
    <button>Offer Draw</button>
    <button>Accept Draw</button>
    <button>RESET GAME</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons  button {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Resign for White</button>
    <button>Resign for Black</button>
    <button>Offer Draw</button>
    <button>Accept Draw</button>
    <button>RESET GAME</button>
</div>
```